# Get element with PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to use an input to upload multiple images. Users can select a "main image" by clicking on the preview of a selected image. I modify the selected image's ID with javascript. For example the user selects 3 images from the input.
2 of them look like this:

```
<div class='uploaded-image' data-index='0' id='image-0'>
   <img src='...'>
</div>
<div class='uploaded-image' data-index='1' id='image-1'>
   <img src='...'>
</div>
```

and the selected image looks like this:

```
<div class='uploaded-image' data-index='0' id='mainimage'>
   <img src='...'>
</div>
```

In my database, I indicate with a tinyint if an image is main image or not. If not, it should be 0, if yes then 1.

I wanted to use simple_html_dom.php to select the actual page and check if it has the 'mainimage' div id, but for some reason it gives '0' value for each uploaded image.

So my question is, how can I check if one of my IDs is 'mainimage' and set it's 'mainimage' value to 1 in database?

Here's a part of my php code:

```
include_once("simple_html_dom.php");

.
.
.

$productid = $link->insert_id;
$statement = $link->prepare("INSERT INTO images(thumbnailimage, productid, mainimage) VALUES(?, ?, ?)");

for ($i = 0; $i < $counted; $i++) {
    $file = $filesTempName[$i];
    if (is_uploaded_file($file) && !empty($file)) {
        $data = "uploads/" . time() . $_FILES["images"]["name"][$i];
        move_uploaded_file($file, $data);

        $html = file_get_html('imageupload.php');
        $mainimage= 0;
        if ($html->getElementById('mainimage'))
            $mainimage= 1;

        $statement->bind_param("sii", $data, $productid, $mainimage);
        $statement->execute();
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you transferring the 'mainid' to the server??  Together with the upload?   Are you sure, that the id gets POSTed?  Use chrome devtools to check this.  Or are you transferring the data with AJAX... ?    (There are image upload libraries that are able to transfer all additional attributes. e.g. DROPZONE.JS

Comment: I see two possibilties  - either send the id  at teh same time as the picture to the server or later  after the upload -  by a simple form  for the user where he can select the main image and  then the script vie REFREH or AJAX  updates the database

Comment: It's inside my ```if (isset($_POST['upload'])) {}``` method. I'm just chagning the element's id with pure javascript.

Comment: What do you mean by "either send the id at the same time..."? I think I'm sending the id when I click on the "send" button, because the id should already be changed then.

Comment: Could you show me an example or something please?

Comment: if you assume that this is sent please **verify** that the ID is really sent before you continue.    How to do this can be found here: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network/reference#headers

Comment: I just tried it with a different id, that already exists on the actual page and it sets the variable to 1. It looks like it can't see it if the id changes. Is there any way to fix this? I have no idea about ajax.